Science Fiction Story about food involving onion and garlic
It was a sf story, most probably by Isaac Asimov, about foods being seasoned with under-ground vegetables, like onion and garlic. The food prepared such has unique tastes, but the conservative society shuns the use of underground vegetables, preferring the purity of over ground foods. This story appeared in a sf book which also contains Isaac Asimov's fiction about thiomoltine.

Asimov's "Good Taste", the answer to Short story by Isaac Asimov about a mental chef
From the TV Tropes Future Food is Artificial page:

The protagonist enters (and wins) the annual cooking contest, and the chief judge raves about his entry until he admits that the key ingredient was a ground bulb of naturally-grown garlic. The judge immediately vomits at the idea of having eaten "A growth from the dirt" and the protagonist is banished. His mother's parting words are; "Can’t you see, Minor-mine, that what you did was not in..."

Not matching, I haven't found a book with both "Good Taste" and "The Endochronic Properties of Resublimated Thiotimoline".

Yes, thank you, "Good Taste" is the one.
